# Reasons for Soft Lock up?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, watchdog, lockup

When we enable `CONFIG_DETECT_SOFTLOCKUP` to detect soft lockups, it creates a new task called `khungtaskd` which will run every 1s. If `khungtaskd` fails to get scheduled for 'n' seconds, then Kernel will declare a soft lockup.

My question is what are the reasons that prevent `khungtaskd` from running? One that I found is- trying to acquire an already acquired spinlock in interrupt context. What are the other reasons which will lead to soft lockup?

Answer (score 1):

Too many interrupt (and computer too slow)? Check `/proc/interrupts` and see.

Some realtime tasks running?

Interrupts almost always have higher priority than other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, on preemption disabled, uniprocessor(non-SMP) systems, any endless loop in a kernel thread will cause a soft-lockup.